# Issue with add team member graph API in US Government (GCC High) tenant

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to make a graph API call to add a member to a team in the US government (GCC high) tenant.

**URL**
POST [https://graph.microsoft.us/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/members](https://graph.microsoft.us/v1.0/teams/%7Bteam-id%7D/members)

**BODY**

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
  "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.us/v1.0/users/{user-id}",
  "roles": []
}
```

The above request fails with a 404 Not Found error. There is no additional information in the error message. I have verified that the user id I am passing is correct. So that is not an issue.

The above request works fine in the case of normal tenant where the graph end point URL ends with ".com" instead of ".us". I find that other graph requests related to teams work fine with the ".us" end point for the US government tenant.

Interestingly, after adding the member to the team using teams web interface I tried adding the member to a private channel using the below URL and with the same request body as above and it worked.

POST [https://graph.microsoft.us/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/members](https://graph.microsoft.us/v1.0/teams/%7Bteam-id%7D/channels/%7Bchannel-id%7D/members)

So I guess the issue here is specific to US government tenant. Is there a fix or workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This API is not implemented yet.

This question is similar to [Cannot Create Events or Team Members in MS Graph National US Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68277042/cannot-create-events-or-team-members-in-ms-graph-national-us-cloud).

Comment: Thanks !! In the other post, it was mentioned that this issue would be fixed this quarter. So will it be fixed by the end of September?